# how to send json as input in postman flow

Tags: postman, postman-flows

How can I use a Json as an input in a flow?
Like the picture below.
Of course, it sends this as a text and gives an error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I had to do to get around this limitation (odd that Postman doesn't allow for it inherently):

[image: {}]

And then in the Collection endpoint, leave the body "raw" and use a variable:

[image: {}]

Anecdotally, the JSON I provided needed to have newline characters after each property removed -- just FYI in case you run into similar trouble.